# Couldn't find Object without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is driving mi crazy. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AppointmentsController#new

Couldn't find Schedule without an ID

app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:25:in `new'
```

I'm sure is a simple thing but I can't see it. Please can somebody point me the issue and how to solve it?

Here is my code

Routes.rb

```
  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root :to => "Doctors#index"
    resources :specialties
    resources :branches

    resources :doctors do
      resources :appointments  
      resources :schedules  
    end
  end

  match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

Relationship

```
Class Appointment ...
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :schedule

end

Class Schedule ...
  belongs_to :doctor
  has_many :appointments
end

Class Doctor ...
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :schedules, dependent: :destroy
end
```

schema

```
  create_table "appointments", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "doctor_id"
    t.date     "adate"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
    t.time     "atime"
    t.string   "personal_id"
    t.string   "insurance_id"
    t.string   "prescription"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.integer  "schedule_id"
  end

  create_table "doctors", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "schedule"
    t.string   "prefix"
  end

  create_table "schedules", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "doctor_id"
    t.boolean  "sun"
    t.boolean  "mon"
    t.boolean  "tue"
    t.boolean  "wed"
    t.boolean  "thu"
    t.boolean  "fri"
    t.boolean  "sat"
  end
```

Controller

```
  def new
    @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:schedule_id])
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:doctor_id])
    @appointment = @doctor.appointments.new
  end
```

_form

```
<h1><%= @doctor.name %></h1>

<%= simple_form_for([@doctor, @appointment], :html => { :multipart => true, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= f.input :full_name %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :adate, as: :date_picker %>
    <%= f.input :atime, as: :time_picker %>
    <%= f.input :personal_id %>
    <%= f.input :insurance_id %>
    <%= f.input :prescription %>


    <div class="controls"><%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>
<% end %>
```

rails console test:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
1.9.3p125 :001 > s = Schedule.last
  Schedule Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" ORDER BY "schedules"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Schedule id: 2, created_at: "2013-01-23 08:40:14", updated_at: "2013-01-23 08:40:14", doctor_id: 1, sun: true, mon: true, tue: true, wed: true, thu: true, fri: true, sat: true> 
1.9.3p125 :002 > s.appointments
  Appointment Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "appointments".* FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."schedule_id" = 2
 => [] 


 root        /:locale(.:format)                                          Doctors#index  
            specialties GET    /:locale/specialties(.:format)                              specialties#index  
                        POST   /:locale/specialties(.:format)                              specialties#create  
          new_specialty GET    /:locale/specialties/new(.:format)                          specialties#new  
         edit_specialty GET    /:locale/specialties/:id/edit(.:format)                     specialties#edit  
              specialty GET    /:locale/specialties/:id(.:format)                          specialties#show  
                        PUT    /:locale/specialties/:id(.:format)                          specialties#update  
                        DELETE /:locale/specialties/:id(.:format)                          specialties#destroy  
               branches GET    /:locale/branches(.:format)                                 branches#index  
                        POST   /:locale/branches(.:format)                                 branches#create  
             new_branch GET    /:locale/branches/new(.:format)                             branches#new  
            edit_branch GET    /:locale/branches/:id/edit(.:format)                        branches#edit  
                 branch GET    /:locale/branches/:id(.:format)                             branches#show  
                        PUT    /:locale/branches/:id(.:format)                             branches#update  
                        DELETE /:locale/branches/:id(.:format)                             branches#destroy  
    doctor_appointments GET    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)          appointments#index  
                        POST   /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)          appointments#create  
 new_doctor_appointment GET    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/new(.:format)      appointments#new  
edit_doctor_appointment GET    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/:id/edit(.:format) appointments#edit  
     doctor_appointment GET    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#show  
                        PUT    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#update  
                        DELETE /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#destroy  
       doctor_schedules GET    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules(.:format)             schedules#index  
                        POST   /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules(.:format)             schedules#create  
    new_doctor_schedule GET    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules/new(.:format)         schedules#new  
   edit_doctor_schedule GET    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules/:id/edit(.:format)    schedules#edit  
        doctor_schedule GET    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules/:id(.:format)         schedules#show  
                        PUT    /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules/:id(.:format)         schedules#update  
                        DELETE /:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules/:id(.:format)         schedules#destroy  
                doctors GET    /:locale/doctors(.:format)                                  doctors#index  
                        POST   /:locale/doctors(.:format)                                  doctors#create  
             new_doctor GET    /:locale/doctors/new(.:format)                              doctors#new  
            edit_doctor GET    /:locale/doctors/:id/edit(.:format)                         doctors#edit  
                 doctor GET    /:locale/doctors/:id(.:format)                              doctors#show  
                        PUT    /:locale/doctors/:id(.:format)                              doctors#update  
                        DELETE /:locale/doctors/:id(.:format)                              doctors#destroy  
                               /*path(.:format)                                            :controller#:action
                               /                                                           :controller#:action
      appointment_steps GET    /appointment_steps(.:format)                                appointment_steps#index
                        POST   /appointment_steps(.:format)                                appointment_steps#create
   new_appointment_step GET    /appointment_steps/new(.:format)                            appointment_steps#new
  edit_appointment_step GET    /appointment_steps/:id/edit(.:format)                       appointment_steps#edit
       appointment_step GET    /appointment_steps/:id(.:format)                            appointment_steps#show
                        PUT    /appointment_steps/:id(.:format)                            appointment_steps#update
                        DELETE /appointment_steps/:id(.:format)                            appointment_steps#destroy
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like? What is the URL?

Comment: Hi @Mischa, you can see my route file content above.
the URLS are:

/en/doctors -  en/doctors/:id/schedules -  en/doctors/:id/appointments

Comment: @evanx, can you add the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: @evanx, I don't think you're getting anything from `params[:schedule_id]`, as the routes don't have that param (unless you're passing it in the URL as `?schedule_id=123`). Could you check?

Comment: @Dogbert, I'm not passing the URL as ?schedule_id=123. I had the form working fine until I had to create a relationship between appointment and schedule because I need to compare some values between those models.

I also think params[:schedule_id] is nil, but I don't know why.

Comment: @evanx, if you dont't want to pass `?shedule_id=123`, then probably you have to modify you routes, so that the route for appointments#new looks like `/:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules/:schedule_id/appointments/new`, but you see, it gets quite long. Anyway, `params[:shedule_id]` will *not* be `nil` only if it can be got from URL: either from `?`-parameter, or from route parameter.

Comment: @NIA if I go with this  '/:locale/doctors/:doctor_id/schedules/:schedule_id/appointments/new', do I have to pass three parameters to the links?

Comment: @NIA - Example: with the nested routes now I have edit_doctor_schedule_appointment_path(appointment.doctor, appointment), do I have to pass the schedule as an argument? if so, how it would look in the controller?

'@schedule = Schedule.find(params[:schedule_id])' '@doctor = Doctor.find(params[:doctor_id])' '@appointment = @doctor.appointments.find(params[:id])'

Comment: @NIA if I want to go this way '?shedule_id=123' how do I set it up in my routes?

Comment: @evanx, no if pass a proper *object* to new_doctor_appointment_path: if this object has *doctor_id* and *shedule_id* properties available, than `..._path` will get them from it. I posted an example in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/4604572 Sorry if I'm mistaken with syntax somehow, I cannot check the code right now. Feel free to comment that Gist if you have any questions on the Gist itself.

Comment: @evanx If you choose to stick to `?shedule_id=123` you don't have to modify your routes, every parameter after `?` is automatically added to `params`. But in this case you will have to explicitly add this parameter to `..._path` calls (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: **Well sorry**, seems like my first idea of passing one object to `..._path` is wrong. Passing object is documented in module [PolymorphicRoutes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes). That is, your worse expectations are true: you will need three parameters if you nest this routes. That's why [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) suggests to avoid deep nesting. Resume: **It would be easier to handle these routes if these three resourses would not be nested into each other. At all.** See https://gist.github.com/4605018

Comment: @NIA do I need the schedules in the url? I just want the relationship to interact with the appointment model.